# Data sources for historical ICE settlement option prices, volume & open interest

Tags: options, data

I am looking for long history for historical settlement option prices, volume & open interest at ICE Europe (specifically fixed income). This seems to be more challenge than I could imagine. ICE themselves said they don't have this data. I was wondering if someone has faced similar challenge and where they got data from...